# How do I lock the header rows of an HTML table from scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to "lock" the header row of an html table of results so that when the browser window scrolls, the header rows remain visible. I need it to work under IE7+/Firefox/Safari/Chrome.

Can this be done with CSS alone, or will I need javascript.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: You may be better off using a positioned element (e.g. `<div style="position: fixed">`) just above the table of results.

Comment: @Williams why not post that as the answer. Its the answer!

Comment: this is **not trivial**. I made a jquery plugin that does this: http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ and it only took 83 commits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot "lock" any sub-element in a table. So the best approach I know is to use a positioned element (as per my comment):

```
<div style="position:fixed">
  <!-- you could have multiple <div> or <span> for the table "header" -->
</div>
<table>
  ...
</table>
```

One thing you might encounter is that you may have to play with the width of the elements inside the positioned `div`. So, you might find it easier to simply drop the `<table>` all together and use `<div>`s.